# Hierarchical paths to access local variables in bind files?

Tags: system-verilog

It's a common methodology to keep assertions, cover points, etc. separate from the design by putting them in a separate module or interface, and use `bind` to attach them to the design, e.g.,

```
module foo (input a);
  wire b = a;
endmodule

interface foo_assertions (input a, b);
  initial #1 assert (b == a);
endinterface
bind foo foo_assertions i_foo_assertions(.*);
```

One problem with this is that it requires maintenance of the port list in `foo_assertions`. However, if `foo` has a `bar` submodule, signals inside `bar` can be accessed conveniently using hierarchical references in the assertions file relative to `foo`, e.g., `assert (i_bar.sig == a)`.

Is there a way to use the hierarchical path syntax for accessing variables declared directly in `foo` as well, eliminating the need for the port list in `foo_assertions`? Note that `foo` is not necessarily the top-level module, so `$root.b` will not work. It looks like `foo.b` works, however is this safe when multiple instances of `foo` exist at the top level?

Comment: 1) there is no such syntax. 2) using wildcards is usually considered a bad methodology. 3) keeping assertions in a separate module could or could be not a good methodology.  Having interfaces to handle assertions only is not a good methodology.

Comment: By wildcards, are you referring to the dot-star syntax in the bind statement? Not using this results in even more maintenance, e.g., when adding or removing ports. Why would you prefer module over interface? I believe the only advantage (and difference) we have found between the two is that modules cannot bind to interfaces, so using interface allows us to write assertions for interfaces used in the RTL using this methodology as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verilog has always had upwards name referencing which is why `foo.b` works (See section 23.8 in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595)). It does not matter how many instances of `foo` there are, as long as you only bind `foo_assertions` into a module named `foo`. Each upward reference applies to the specific instance that reference is underneath.

When referring to the top-level module in a hierarchical path, you have been using an upwards reference without necessarily realizing it.

Comment: I did indeed believe that references to modules outside the local scope were resolved in a downward fashion from top.